# PHP Parse html start and end bracket

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a problem with parsing text in brackets with PHP

Here is what i want to do. I have a textarea and i input this information.

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry

[if city="x"]My specific agreement text for the city x[/if]

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry

[if city="y"]My specific agreement text for the city y[/if]

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry

[if city="y"]My specific agreement text 2 for the city y[/if]
```

Then i would like to render the text like this.

```
<?php
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];
$city = "y";

// DO SOME MAGIC I DON'T KNOW... To remove the text between the [if city="x"]Text[/if] and keep the textsnippets between [if city="y"]Text[/if]

// END OF MAGIC.

echo $textarea // Now the text that are in brackets of city = y only shows.
?>
```

End result should be like this (when echo )

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
>   typesetting industry
>
> **My specific agreement text for the city y**
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry
>
> **My specific agreement text 2 for the city y**

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to do here? Match all the text between `]` and `[` in the even numbered lines? Or actually evaluate the expression in the initial `[…`]` on those lines?

Comment: did you tried something? please provide some code

Comment: What is it you want to achieve here? It's not clear... can you please elaborate?

Comment: this regex might work for you `\[.*city="y"\](.*)\[\/if\]`, [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vB0pO0/1)

Comment: Okey, to elaborate. The text i want to input is a text for a standard agreement for buying a online course. But the agreement is conditional depending on what city you are from in some parts of the agreement. So if you are from New York some parts of the text is different if are taking the course from London.

Comment: You need to put that information the question, with examples of both outputs.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the regex by "anonymous" i could figure out a solution that works for me. Don't think its the prittiest but it works.

```
$city = 'x';
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
<br><br>
[if city="x"]My specific agreement text for the city x[/if]
<br><br>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
<br><br>
[if city="y"]My specific agreement text for the city y[/if]
<br><br>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
<br><br>
[if city="y"]My specific agreement text 2 for the city y[/if]';


$reg = preg_match_all('(\[if.*](.*)\[\/if\])', $string, $matches);


foreach( $matches[0] as $key => $value ) {
    if( strpos($value,'city="'. $city .'"') !== false ) {

    } else {
        $string = str_replace($value, '', $string);
    }
}

$string = str_replace('[if city="'. $city .'"]', '', $string);
$string = str_replace('[/if]', '', $string);


echo $string;
```